# Parse a string containing integers into a List<int>

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-2.0

I want to let the user enter integers in the following ways:

- Numbers separated by commas: 1,3,122,64000,27 etc
- Ranges of numbers: 37-2000
- A mixture of the above: 55,2,1-10000,65000-65007,2182

How can I parse a string that may be in any of the forms above an end up with a List of int?

So for example: 1-5,6,7-8 should give a list containing the ints 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

I'm pretty new to C# so some example code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What would you want as result in the list from a range like "1-10000"? Should it add 10000 numbers to the list?

Comment: @Guffa: Yes, 1-10000 would add all the numbers from 1 to 10K to the list. E.g., 1-5 would add the ints 1,2,3,4,5 to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
var query =
    from x in text.Split(',')
    let y = x.Split('-')
    let b = int.Parse(y[0].Trim())
    let e = int.Parse(y[y.Length - 1].Trim())
    from n in Enumerable.Range(b, e - b + 1)
    select n;

var result = query.ToList();
```

I would suggest adding some error handling, but if your input is in the correct format this works.

---

** EDIT**: The .NET 2.0 version.

```
var result = new List<int>();
foreach (var x in text.Split(','))
{
    var y = x.Split('-');
    var b = int.Parse(y[0].Trim());
    var e = int.Parse(y[y.Length - 1].Trim());
    for (var n = b; n <= e; n++)
    {
        result.Add(n);
    }
}
```

Much the same... :-)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is for me that we have to do this with .NET 2.0.

Comment: @stanleyR - I added the .NET 2.0 version to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! x may not have a '-' in it; it may just be a single integer value. E.g., text may be 1-2,5,222,5-9. Does this handle that? Thanks again!

Comment: @stanleyR - yes, it does. If you have a string "24" that you split using "-" then you just get back an array with one string in it. That's why I parse the first and the last value in the array. It handles single and double value arrays nicely.

Answer (score 2):

String.split splitting by comma , will give you all you need then if a group contains - split for it again and you have the two range values

Answer (score 0):

Tokenise the string based on the ',' then parse that list of individual numbers or ranges.

From memory there is a Split(..) method on List that you can use to get the tokens. Then just test fot the presence of a '-' (if its the first character then its negative, not a range obviously).